# An ES6 array of numbers - Double last number, delete the first number

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6

I'm writing a JavaScript function for an array, based on a geographic sequence. \$[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]\$, etc.

> This function needs to populate the next number in the sequence 
>   $$item_n = item_{n-1} * 2$$ 
>   If there are more than \$10\$ items in the array, remove the first
>   (smallest) number.
>
> If the array reaches \$2^{15}\$ (no idea what this is), reset the array to
>   its original contents - \$[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]\$.

I have it working, but I feel this could be written more efficiently...

```
updateSequence() {
  var sequence = this.get("geometricSequence");

  // Modify the sequence here
  function* values(sequence) {
    for (let prop of Object.keys(sequence)) 
    yield sequence[prop];
  }
  let arr = Array.from(values(sequence));

  const lastIndex = arr.length - 1;
  const lastValue = parseInt(arr[lastIndex]) * 2;
  arr.push(lastValue);
  if (lastIndex > 9) {
    arr.slice(0, 1);
  }
  if (lastValue > 32768) {
    arr = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16];
  }
  this.set('geometricSequence', arr);
}
```

Comment: Could you include the code for _this.get("geometricSequence")_ and an example how this data looks?

Answer (score 2):

This will be cleaner if you implement it as a pure function, which takes the sequence as an argument.  You can make `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]` a default value for that argument, so that you can start the sequence with nothing.  Taking this approach, the function simplifies to:

```
function updateSequence(arr = updateSequence.default) {
  const last = arr[arr.length-1]
  if (last == 32768) return updateSequence.default

  const ret = arr.concat(last * 2)
  return ret.length > 10 ? ret.slice(1) : ret
}
updateSequence.default = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
```

You can test that it works like this:

```
// test it
var arr = updateSequence()
for (i=0; i<15; i++) {
  console.log(arr)
  arr = updateSequence(arr)
}
```

which prints the following:

```
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 ]
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 ]
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 ]
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 ]
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 ]
[ 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024 ]
[ 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048 ]
[ 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096 ]
[ 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192 ]
[ 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384 ]
[ 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768 ]
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ]
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 ]
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 ]
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `obj.get("geometricSequence");` presumably already contains an array, you can skip the whole shenanigans with the iterator and directly work on that. Also, if you change the order of the `if` statements at the end you can save some work by not doing slices on an array you eventually gonna replace later anyway. So:

```
updateSequence() {
  let arr = this.get("geometricSequence");

  const lastIndex = arr.length - 1;
  const lastValue = parseInt(arr[lastIndex]) * 2;

  arr.push(lastValue);

  if (lastValue > 32768)
    arr = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16];
  else if (lastIndex > 9)
    arr.slice(0, 1);

  this.set('geometricSequence', arr);
}
```